# How do I report results from a Tukey post hoc analysis?

Tags: post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test, psychology

I examined all possible comparisons in the Tukey test (here is the chart - sorry it's a little unclear)

https://scontent.fybz2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/74701623_502065310380147_7439754835601129472_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&_nc_oc=AQm6G2v5LQgKivpBxIXi3g_BCiOGuY7HJzHBID_OVor82oTsg9z2q-ltvUqrdZnVi4U&_nc_ht=scontent.fybz2-1.fna&oh=65a805e92c970f5c1b9b1338a6fe26ba&oe=5E534598

How do I report the findings? As in, how do I know which is significant to which. I have many significant values, but how do I know which numbers to look at to say something like ex. X4 was significantly different from X6, X1, X5, X3, and X2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I cannot open your link as it expired. However, I believe, as POC mentioned, the easiest way to approach a Tukey-HSD test is to look at all the different variables in a table and then cross-check which variables are significant and vice versa. What program do you use?

E.g. Let us imagine a very very simple dataset consisting of daily hours of sunshine and countries. After doing an ANOVA test you realise it is significant. But, you do not know which countries differ significantly from each other. You perform Tukey-HSD test and create a table, as below.

```
Country               p-value     significantly different
Denmark * Sweden:     0.90                  no
Denmark * Egypt:      0.01                  yes
Denmark * Australia   0.05                  yes
Egypt * Sweden:       0.01                  yes
Egypt * Australia:    0.25                  no
Sweden * Australia:   0.05                  yes
```

If this is not clear enlighten me in your dataset and program used, please.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and often see way to report post hoc test in ANOVA is to do a table in which each column represents significantly groups, and groups in the same column are not significantly different form each other. For your example, it would be

```
|X4|  |
|  |X1|
|  |X2|
|  |X3|
|  |X5|
|  |X6|
```

X4 would be on the right or left depending if it means is greater (right) or lesser (left) of other means. You can add columns, let's say x6 is significantly greater than other means and X4 is significantly less than other means. And other means have no other statistically different between each other, this would lead to a table like :

```
|X4|  |  |
|  |X1|  |
|  |X2|  |
|  |X3|  |
|  |X5|  |
|  |  |X6|
```

A mean can be also in two columns. If X5, for instance, is not different from X1, X2, X3, and X6, this would yield :

```
|X4|  |  |
|  |X1|  |
|  |X2|  |
|  |X3|  |
|  |X5|X5|
|  |  |X6|
```

Hope this will help!